# pass php array to jquery with getJSON

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, object

**updated:**
i use this:

```
$.getimagesarr = function(operation) {
  return $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'operations.php',
      data: {'operation':operation},
      async: false
    }).responseText
}


var jsonstring = $.getimagesarr('getimg');
var data = (new Function("return " + jsonstring))() 
if (data){
   ....
}
```

**old:**
i want to pass a php aray to jQuery:

```
$.getimagesarr = function() {
    $.getJSON('operations.php', {'operation':'getimglist'}, function(data){
        var arr = new Array();
        arr = data;
        return arr;
    });  
}

var data = $.getimagesarr();
if (data){
 jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {
     ....
    });
}
```

it return undefined

in php i have this:

```
function getimglist(){
    $results = $_SESSION['files'];
    echo json_encode($results);
}
```

it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

The `return arr;` line isn't going to return a value for the `$.getimagesarr` function. It's going to execute asynchronously, after the `$.getJSON()` call has finished. You should move the bottom area of code to within the success event handler for the `$.getJSON()` call:

```
$.getimagesarr = function() {
    $.getJSON('operations.php', {'operation':'getimglist'}, function(data){
        if (data){
            jQuery.each(data, function(i, val) {
                ....
            });
        }
    });  
};
```

Comment: i really need a function, i use this in more places, i don't want to put all this code 3..4... times!how to return a value in a variable?something like this: var data = $.getimagesarr();

Comment: To do that you would need to use a synchronous AJAX call, which brings with it a lot of evil. It can cause performance issues in the browser and/or cause the browser to hang. I would **strongly** advise against that route.

An event-based approach, though painful for any refactoring you may have to do, is the way to go. I mean, "asynchronous" is literally the first letter of the acronym "AJAX" (Asynchronous JavaScript And XML).

Comment: I believe that should work, but remember that it will block execution of your script while it waits for the data. I would still strongly suggest you consider refactoring to accomodate using an asynchronous request.